# How can i use the one SFDC org class methods to another SFDC org using Rest Api?

Tags: rest-api

i want to integrate to salesforce org and use one org class methods in another org using rest api

please give me one example for better understanding... thanks in advance..

Comment: Why REST specifically? Can you try SOAP? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/25415/320

Answer (score 1):

This project might help.  You could probably do this via Apex.

https://github.com/anandbn/apex-oauth-rest